# Convert coordinate from one world coordinate system to object coordinate system

Tags: matlab, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I am more interested in the mathematics behind this problem, but am using matlab to try and solve this problem.  I have an object, positioned using the world coordinate system at (W<sub>x</sub>, W<sub>y</sub>, W<sub>z</sub>)

I would like to calculate the coordinates of this point using the object coordinate system  (O<sub>x</sub>, O<sub>y</sub>, O<sub>z</sub>)

To do this, I first need to calculate the axes of the object coordinate system.

**Step 1** is to find the Normal (N<sub>x</sub>, N<sub>y</sub>, N<sub>z</sub>)

(assuming that this is not the world z-axis). My object has a yaw, pitch and roll angle applied so I need to find my normal relative to this.

To do this I use a rotational matrix and perform the operations in the order stated above.

[image]

**Step 2** is to calculate the arbitrary axes.

If abs(N<sub>x</sub> < 1/64) and abs(N<sub>y</sub> < 1/64)

(Ax<sub>x</sub>, Ax<sub>y</sub>, Ax<sub>z</sub>) = cross product of world y-axis (0,1,0) and the Normal

else

(Ax<sub>x</sub>, Ax<sub>y</sub>, Ax<sub>z</sub>) = cross product of world z-axis (0,0,1) and the Normal

(Ay<sub>x</sub>, Ay<sub>y</sub>, Ay<sub>z</sub>) = cross product of N and Ax

I then scale my arbitrary axes by dividing by the sqrt of the sum of the squares.

**Step 3** - Transform the coordinate

To transform the coordinate you point multiply the initial coordinate by each of the axes.

O<sub>x</sub> = W<sub>x</sub> * Ax<sub>x</sub> + W<sub>y</sub> * Ax<sub>y</sub> + W<sub>z</sub> * Ax<sub>z</sub>

O<sub>y</sub> = W<sub>x</sub> * Ay<sub>x</sub> + W<sub>y</sub> * Ay<sub>y</sub> + W<sub>z</sub> * Ay<sub>z</sub>

O<sub>z</sub> = W<sub>x</sub> * N<sub>x</sub> + W<sub>y</sub> * N<sub>y</sub> + W<sub>z</sub> * N<sub>z</sub>

DXF for autocad takes the object coordinates, the Normal vector and a rotation about the normal vector.
This appears to be working reasonable well at positioning the coordinate, but with some issues:

1. When I use the method above, I find that sometimes my objects are rotated 180 degrees. Digging into this, sometimes the Arbitrary x-axis is negative, sometimes it is positive. This may account for some objects being rotated, but Autocad does not actually reference this Ax vector. It calculates it. This means that I may have to correct this with a rotation about the normal,  but I do not what it to always apply (I cannot simply look for a negative value and rotate if negative, as sometimes the object is required to be placed in this direction).I do not know how to overcome this.
2. If I apply a roll angle to the object and work through this process, the roll angle is not applied correctly. Instead this appears to translate this angle as an Yaw and Site change, but not actually the intended rotation. I cannot see what I have done using the above formula.

Comment: I would assume from your discussion that the angles A, B, and C are known. Where do they come from? I.e., what is generating these angles and are you sure you know what their definitions are based on?

Comment: Yes, the angles A, B and C are known. They are the rotations about the axes. C is rotation about the Z axis, A is about the X-axis, and B about the Y. These angles can be anything I specify to make the object face in a certain direction. For the sake of discussion we can think of them as user generated inputs.

Comment: And the angles are applied in pitch (B), roll (A), yaw (C) order? And what is this normal vector (Nx,Ny,Nz)? Your description says you need to find it in Step 1, but I don't see where you do this. Then you use it as an input to calculations in Step 2.

Comment: The rotations are applied in yaw (C), pitch (B), roll(A) order. The normal vector is calculated by taking the world Z-Axis (0,0,1) - the normal before any rotation, and applying each of the rotations to it. The picture shows the rotation matrices in the correct order, and the end result when all three rotations are applied. Because I am using (0,0,1), this leaves me with just the blue values for the normal vector. Top blue value is X, middle value is y, and bottom is Z. Together this is my normal vector

Comment: More to this, I have realised that I do not need to calculate arbitrary axis like I do above as I already know the rotations.  Arbitrary x-axis is simply the red values of the equation, and the Arbitrary Y-axis is the green values.  This gives the same results as the scaled arbitrary axis.

Comment: Now you have me really confused. The order of rotations you have in your matrix multiply clearly show the order as pitch (B) first, roll (A) second, and yaw (C) third. Rotation matrices essentially operate from right-to-left. If you want the order to be C first, B second, A last, then you need to multiply in RxRyRz order. The columns of this result are the original axes vectors expressed in the new coordinate system.